# why does it not iterate all the elements of the IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable

I have this code:

```
public static void myMethodMytype paramObject, IEnumerable<MyType> paramObjects)
{

    IEnumerable<Mytype> ieFilteredObjects = paramObjects.Where(x=>x.IDType == paramObject.IDType);

    if (ieFilteredObjects.Count() == 2)
    {
        foreach (MyType iterator in ieFilteredObjects)
        {
            iterator.MyProperty = null;
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, ieFilteredObjects has 2 elements, but in the foreach, only update the first element, and the exit of the foreach.

If in the foreach I use this:

```
foreach (MyType iterator in ieFilteredObjects.ToList())
```

then it works as expected.

Why I have to convert the IEnumerable to a list?

Thanks.

Comment: Your apparently incorrect code and the correct code should functionally behave the same (allow you to iterate the enumerable). The reason for the failure, in my opinion, is not shown in the code you have presented.

Comment: Your query count may change between your `Count()` method and the `GetEnumerator` inside foreach as it is executing the `Where` clause each time you iterate. is `paramObjects` being mutated outside the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>IEnumerable can only be iterated once.</strike> You cannot iterate twice on an IEnumerable and **expect to get the same values**.

For instance, the IEnumerable may come from a `yield return` function, each time you call `GetEnumerator()` on the IEnumerable you start a new call to this function which may create new values.

This is not a common use case, but it exists. I already had this kind of bug in production.

The solution is to *cache* the result of the first iteration. A common technique is to use a linq: `.ToList()` to create a `IList`, that you can iterate ad infinitum

In your code you iterate at least twice:

- ieFilteredObjects.Count()
- foreach (MyType iterator in ieFilteredObjects)

Comment: What do you mean it can only be iterated once? I successfully iterate enumerables multiple times all the time.

Comment: `IEnumerable can only be iterated once` I don't think so. Where did you find this?

Comment: You iterate an `IEnumerable` by retrieving a new `IEnumerator` each time. Your answer is incorrect.

Comment: You need to clarify that Linq is lazy evaluated and thus multiple iterations can have different results if the underlying collection is changed between iterations, instead of saying it can only be iterated once.